# Setting Value of One Column same as another column in a table during insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Line_Production_Plan` in SQL Server; it has a `UID` column (int, auto-increment, identity).

It also has multiple other columns. One of them is `execution_priority` (int, not null).

When I insert a new row into the table (via a stored procedure (without passing `execution_priority` or `UID` as parameters)), I want `execution_priority` to take up the same value as the corresponding `UID` column in during insert. Is there a way to set the default value of a column, equal to another upon insert?

The execution, priority needs to be changed from time to time. Hence I can't use identity or auto increment.

Comment: Can you explain why using a default value for `execution_priority` cannot be done?  A default value like 1, or 100, or .... , or `default_execution_priority` ?

Comment: What about allowing `NULL` in `execution_priority`  and selecting (or adding a computed column) `ISNULL(execution_priority, UID)`?

Comment: Why not just leave your execution_priority NULL? Then you can easily update it when needed. The final part would be that whatever code is utilizing could simply use a coalesce or isnull.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IDENT_CURRENT` to get the last identity value generated for the table `Line_Production_Plan`.

Try this code:

```
INSERT INTO Line_Production_Plan (execution_priority) 
       VALUES ((SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Line_Production_Plan')));
```